# cannot accept jquery selector from managed bean jsf2 primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, jquery-selectors, primefaces, managed-bean

I want to execute  jquery from managed bean but I have this problem wtih selector :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: lesarticles
```

here is the managed bean code :

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#tabView\\:lesarticles').children().find('table tbody tr td div').css('display', 'none');");
```

and here is the tree of components

```
<p:tabView id="tabView">
<p:tab>
<p:datatable id="lesarticles">......
```

and when I run :

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#tabView:lesarticles').children().find('table tbody tr td div').css('display', 'none');");
```

I have also error

how can I resolve that

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to minimize the escaping issues just do

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("easyNameFunc();");
```

and in your js create

```
function easyNameFunc(){
    $('#tabView\\:lesarticles').children().find('table tbody tr td div').css('display', 'none');
}
```

That way you can do a better debugging and have less pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

To properly escape a colon in an id (for jQuery selector) required 4 backslashes for me. I struggled with this for many hours, maybe this will help somebody else. If you look at whats actually sent to browser in Firebug, 2 backslashes becomes only one and you get the error. 
change:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#tabView\\:lesarticles').children().find('table tbody tr td div').css('display', 'none');");
```

to:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#tabView\\\\:lesarticles').children().find('table tbody tr td div').css('display', 'none');");
```

That will at least get you past the error.